# how to get double looping using foreach($data as $buff) in codeigniter example first select destination and second form select is departure

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

```
public function get_trayek() {
        $transportation=$this->input->post('id_transportation');
        $data=$this->main_model->get_trayek($transportation);
        $data_trayek='<option value="">----- Pilih Destination -----</option>';
        foreach($data as $buff){
            $data_trayek.= '<option value="'.$buff->Id_trayek.'">'.$buff->destination.'</option>';
        }


        $data_trayek1='<option value="">----- Pilih Departure -----</option>';


     1. 
     foreach($data as $buff){
                $data_trayek1.= '<option value="'.$buff->Id_trayek.'">'.$buff->departure.'</option>';

        }
        echo json_encode(array('data'=>$data_trayek));
    }
```

Comment: do like this echo json_encode(array('data_trayek'=>$data_trayek,'data_trayek1' => $data_trayek1));

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
public function get_trayek() {
    $transportation=$this->input->post('id_transportation');
    $data=$this->main_model->get_trayek($transportation);
    $data_trayek='<option value="">----- Pilih Destination -----</option>';
    foreach($data as $buff){
        $data_trayek.= '<option value="'.$buff->Id_trayek.'">'.$buff->destination.'</option>';
    }

    $data_trayek1='<option value="">----- Pilih Departure -----</option>';

    foreach($data as $buff){
            $data_trayek1.= '<option value="'.$buff->Id_trayek.'">'.$buff->departure.'</option>';

    }
    echo json_encode(array('data'=>array("destination"=>$data_trayek,"departure"=>$data_trayek1));
}
```

you can in ajax response by `data.destination` and `data.departure`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single loop like

```
public function get_trayek() {
        $transportation=$this->input->post('id_transportation');
        $data=$this->main_model->get_trayek($transportation);
        $data_trayek='<option value="">----- Pilih Destination -----</option>';
        $data_trayek1='<option value="">----- Pilih Departure -----</option>';

        foreach($data as $buff){
            $data_trayek.= '<option value="'.$buff->Id_trayek.'">'.$buff->destination.'</option>';
            $data_trayek1.= '<option value="'.$buff->Id_trayek.'">'.$buff->departure.'</option>';
        }
        echo json_encode(array('data'=>array("destination"=>$data_trayek,"departure"=>$data_trayek1));
    }
```